# why Microsoft Access database is updating in bin debug folder not in local folder?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

i'm using Microsoft  Microsoft Access database in my application, It is not updating in the local folder but in the Bin it is working fine what to do to update the local  Microsoft Access database i as have to fetch the details from that folder initially when my application is Up?

Comment: updating as in you are inserting/modifying data inside of it?

Comment: mdb file is set to "copy to output directory: always (or 'if newer')" (in your solution, select properties on .mdb file), and your connection string points to .mdb database in same folder relative to .exe.